# Testing a function defined within another function

Tags: node.js, jestjs

I have been trying to test this function.

```
// stripe.js
async function stripeHelper(stripe, type){
  if(type == 'customer'){
    await stripe.customers.retrieve()
  }
  if(type == 'customers'){
    await stripe.customers.list().autoPagingEach()
  }
}
```

I am able to mock the first 'if' using this variable in the .test.js file

```
// stripe.test.js
const myJsFile = require(stripe.js)
stripe = {
  customers: {
    retrieve: async () => { // stuff }
}

expect(await myJsFile.stripeHelper(
  stripe, 'customer').toEqual();
```

But I haven't been able to test the second 'if' where 'type' is equal to 'customers', I have tried this:

```
// stripe.test.js
stripe = {
  customers: {
    retrieve: async () => { // stuff }
    list: async () => {
      function autoPagingEach (){// stuff}
      return { autoPagingEach: autoPagingEach }
    }
}

expect(await myJsFile.stripeHelper(
  stripe, 'customers').toEqual();
}
```

So, when executing `stripe.customers.list().autoPagingEach()` my test returns error because `.autoPagingEach()` is not a function

Basically, I just need to simulate the `autoPagingEach()` function within the variable(stripe) in my test file

Any ideas?

Comment: How about removing the `async` keyword in `list`? It will wrap your object as a Promise, but the only promise you need seems to be `list.autoPagingEach`. list: () => {
      function autoPagingEach (){// stuff}
      return { autoPagingEach: autoPagingEach }
    }

Comment: Reformatting a littlem notice the async in `autoPagingEach`: list: () => {
      async function autoPagingEach (){// stuff}
      return { autoPagingEach }
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you need to do is this:

```
// stripe.test.js
stripe = {
  customers: {
    retrieve: async () => { // stuff }
    list: () => {
      async function autoPagingEach (){// stuff}
      return { autoPagingEach: autoPagingEach }
    }
}

expect(await myJsFile.stripeHelper(
  stripe, 'customers').toEqual();
}
```

`autoPagingEach` should be the asynchronous function, not `list`.